# Dragging bookmarks into folder in chrome bookmarksbar

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I don't know if this is a bug, but I can't seem to drag bookmarks that live within a folder in Chromes bookmark bar into a nested folder within that same folder.

Is this an error on my part or chromes inner workings?

I use xmarks for syncing bookmarks across browsers and tried deactivating it, but no help.

Comment: Confirm behavior.  Witnessed to happening on both Linux and Windows.  Almost certainly not an error on your part.  Seems to be deficiency in  Chrome's design.

Comment: My paranoid conspiracy theory opinion, Google doesn't care about bookmarks.  They want you to search for everything, so that you are forced to see their ads.

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue on my PC. I have no problem dragging a bookmark from a folder to a subfolder. For reference, my chrome version is 29.0.1547.66.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly long standing [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=14222) but it looks like it has been resolved. I can confirm that as of 29.0.1547.66 on Windows that it has been fixed.

Comment: oh my! it really has been fixed. Have been plagued with this issue for a year and one hour later after posting it's fixed? what a wierd coincidence